# React router keep query params when changing route and back

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a website with different pages based on `react-router` `v4`. Each page have `url` `query` based filters it means filter setting are stored on url like `mysite.com/page1?filterKey=value`.

My goal is to keep filter values on query when user back from another page ( `mysite.com/page2`).

Comment: Are you using redux?

Comment: no, I am not using redux

Comment: redux would be a good choice here, just save the filtervalue to the global redux state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found other one solutions using `react` `hooks` based global state:

```
const [podcastsUrlSearch, updateGlobalState] = useGlobalState('podcastsUrlSerach')
useLayoutEffect(() => {
  if (!isEqual(props.location.search, podcastsUrlSearch)) {
    updateGlobalState(props.location.search)
  }
  if (podcastsUrlSearch) {
    props.history.replace({ ...props.history.location, search: podcastsUrlSearch })
  }
}, [])

useLayoutEffect(() => {
  updateGlobalState(props.location.search)
}, [props.location.search])
```

Answer (score 2):

The only 2 ways I see is either to use redux as Will Jenkins suggested, or to set the state in the parent container (either App.js, or the file handling your routes) :

- In the parent container, define the function

```
setQuery = query => this.setState({query})
```

- Pass the function to the child component
- In the child component, pass the query on componentDidMount :

```
componentDidMount (){
    this.setQuery( decodeURIComponent(querySearch(this.props.location.search).param) )
}
```

Comment: What about `locatio.state`? Maybe somehow possible use it for my goal?

Comment: the location.state won't stay forever, if you update the page multiple times until clearing the cache, you will lose your values

Answer (score -1):

For example using a dropdown as a filter

use -->localStorage.setItem("companyDrpDwnValue")

on onChange event

and call the the below method to intialize the param on ComponentDidMount ,with which you were filtering the table

and filter the array with the filter param to get your filtered array

Comment: Method to call on COmponentDidMount to set the chosen filter(s):

public keepFiltersOnPageRender() {
    this.company = localStorage.getItem("companyDrpDwnValue");
    this.country = localStorage.getItem("countryDrpDwnValue");
  }